# Calculating frequency of only visible cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having trouble calculating the frequency (in order to plot a histogram) from filtered data.

As for now, on Sheet1 I have the data of ten temperatures with a filter, I assigned a name for each Temperature which takes all the range (for example, the name Temperature1 takes Sheet1!A:A).

On Sheet2, the user selects one assigned name (for example Temperature1) and the calculation of the max, min, intervals, frecuency and plot of the histogram gets done.
The way I calculate the frequency right now is using {=FREQUENCY(INDIRECT(Temperature1);A2:A13)}

Where A2:A13 are the intervals that I have previously calculated.

Using the function "SUBTOTAL", =SUBTOTAL(1;INDIRECT(Temperature1)), I managed to get the average, max, min, etc. of only the filtered (visible) cells. But can't find anything similar for frequency. My boss doesn't allow me to use macros with vba. Is there a way or a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line of thinking: create a pivot table based on your data and filter that table. Then calculate the histogram based on that data instead of calculating it based on the original data.

In my opinion a better and more robust way to achieve this is to add a `BIN` column to your original data table, in which the interval is calculated. For example, if your temperatures are between 12.0 and 23.4 degrees and you like a 2 degree interval, add a column with the formula `ROUND([@Temperature]/2)*2`. Next, create a pivot table with the `BIN` value in the columns and the frequency in the values of the pivot table. This way, you can filter the values in the `REPORT FILTER` of the pivot table. This also makes graphing easy, as Excel can easily create a graph based on a pivot table.

You could even base this `BIN` field on a parameter (e.g. number of bins), making this a bit more flexible (at the cost of some added complexity).